# Unable to get PCI and PCIe Sound Cards to Work

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu.  I'm attempting to get PCI and PCIe Sound Cards to be recognized by ALSA and nothing I've tried has solved the problem.  I've attempted to get two different sound cards (Digigram VX222v2 and Digigram VX222e) to work on Ubuntu 24.04.4.  I've identified that both of these sound cards utilize the snd-pcxhr ALSA driver.  Entering a modinfo snd-pcxhr in terminal returns information, indicating that the driver is present in the kernel.  The user is included in the Audio group, so I don't think it's a permissions issue.  I'm certain that I'm missing a step but I've been unable to find any information online that leads to these sound cards being recognized by the system.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?